# Which fence wood and paint/stain is this?

Tags: wood, outdoor, fence, stain

I was looking at this example

https://anchorfence.wordpress.com/2014/04/

Can cedar be prepared to look like it? Is it paint or stain? Because it looks so shiny and smooth.

[image]

Comment: From the article: "Chesterfield with CertaGrain is a tongue-and-groove fence produced from premium top quality polyvinyl chloride (PVC)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Is it paint or stain?"**- neither, that fence is made of plastic. It is manufactured that color.

**"Can cedar be prepared to look like it?"** - the grain uniformity and absence of knots and defects is unrealistic, natural cedar will have natural imperfections. If you choose your lumber carefully you can select pieces that look nicest to you. A high quality semi-transparent exterior stain will give you some sheen with a bit of tint, along with a lot of sanding to make it smooth, is probably the closest you will get to the unnatural look of PVC fencing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a vinyl fence. You could get a solid stain to match the color, but it won't be shiny. You could polyurethane it, but the sun degrades it after a couple of years, and you'll have to repeatedly refinish the fence.